# I can connect to team foundation project, but can't load from source control because project folder doesn't exist

Tags: tfs

So, I screwed up earlier. I was attempting to install reporting services into TFS (which for a single server required that I delete the existing TFS configuration and re-create it with reporting). I failed to note that I couldn't install reporting services with a client operating system though, so I'm back where I started on that count - sort of.

Before I removed the configuration, I used the TFS Backup Power Tool (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) to backup my projects (as I have regularly for quite a while), so I have a series of backups to pull from. However, I'm having difficulty restoring my project back to TFS.

Originally, I configured TFS, ran the restore tool and put all the databases back in from the backups, but that didn't work because I couldn't view the collections in the TFS Admin Console  and thus couldn't access my projects.  Instead, I created a new collection in the TFS Admin Console, created a new Team Project in Visual Studio and tried to just copy the files from my old project into the new one.

I can see my old team project in there, but if I attempt to load the solution from it, I get an error:

> TF10175: The team project folder $/Stuff does not exist. Contact your
>   Team Foundation Server administrator and ask that it be created.

However, I can't find any particular way to create that folder without simply creating a new project, mapping it locally and then I'm without my files again until I re-copy them. Now, I can do that and don't otherwise have any ties to my old team project except that I also want all my work items from it into my new one.

Here's my problem - I'd like to be able to restore everything back to how it was before this ill-conceived upgrade. I'd like to see my team project in TFS Source Control and load it as well as be able to access all my Work Items.

Now, I can copy my entire project over to the new team project and I'm good on that front, but that doesn't give me my Work Items. I tried using the TFS Integration tool (http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) to copy the work items from one project to the other, but it is unable to see the old Team Project unless I have it connected in Visual Studio. And if it's open in VS, I can't do the operation because "The process cannot access the file because it's being used by another process."  When I close VS, my old team project disappears into source control and the Integration tool can no longer see it.

Thus here seem to be my two options:

1) Can anyone share some insight into how to load my old team project from source control (currently unbound, but when I bind it, I get the $/Stuff doesn't exist error) so I can access all the files + Work Items?

or

2) Can anyone share some insight into how I can move the Work Items from my old project to the new one? And I'm not interested in that method of using Excel to just get the basic information - I need all the links that are in there and those apparently don't map to Excel.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, never did get any responses - that's quite all right though.  Here's what I've done in the meantime and now finally have a collection attached, the backup from the old databases (saved via the TFS Backup Powertool) and all my work items.

I recreated the Collection in the TFS Administration Console with the same name as the previous Collection, then created a Team Project in Visual Studio again, but with a new name. I then restored only the Project backup I wanted from the TFS Backup Powertool (did not include the TFS configuration database or Collection database) to its original name (don't really have a choice on that one).

In Visual Studio, I connected to both the New and Original Projects (the original was in the Source Control) in different instances of Visual Studio. I manually copied each of my work items over from the old project to the new (mainly because it was extremely important I preserve the history of the project for my client - thus couldn't use the Excel export/import). That covered the Work Items.  Next I needed the source code, but that was a simple matter of copying the files I had locally into my newly mapped New Project path, then adding them in the Source Control Explorer. I finally checked everything in and was good until today.

I connected to TFS in Visual Studio and received a TF30046 error (essentially the InstanceID doesn't match what's expected). Apparently, if you change the configuration of TFS between backups, Visual Studio/TFS (not sure which) will create a new InstanceID for your database. Take a look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909690(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909690%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for information on how to change this InstanceID.  However, unlike the steps in that documentation, I did not have a TFSBuild, TFSIntegration or TFSVersionControl. An hour later after reinstalling TFS2010, I still didn't have them. Doesn't matter - look in the Properties in SQL Management Studio for the database containing your desired new Project, under Extended Properties and you'll find the InstanceID you're looking for. Copy in the value Visual Studio gave as the expected value (including the dashes - even though my original value didn't have them), OK out of that, reconnect on Visual Studio and the project will load up right as rain.